# Custom tproxy module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, iptables, transparentproxy

I am trying to develop a **custom tproxy module**  .The current tproxy module inside the Linux kernel is working under certain iptable rules .

How the iptable and tproxy module works when a packet was arrived .In my case how can I integrate my custom module with the iptable. What is the right approach to develop a custom t-proxy module ? Please help me..

Thanks